# Dashboards failed to deploy using outbound changeset

Tags: deployment, dashboard, change-set, custom-report-type

Pre-requisites already deployed:

1. Reports & Dashboards Folders
2. Custom Report Types
3. Reports

When uploading Dashboards I get this unhelpful error :

> Your upload failed. We're sending you an e-mail with more
>   information.

Unhelpful email given :

> The following outbound change set upload failed due to a system error:
>
> Change set: ... Organization: ...
>   (Developer Sandbox) User: ... Error Number: 674932773-56394 (245827274)
>
> Please try to upload your change set again. If it does not succeed,
>   contact Customer Support and provide the error number listed above.
>
> Thank You, salesforce.com

What am I missing? How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Salesforce is buggy.**

You have to check each Dashboard for any report(s) that **cannot be displayed**.

Cannot be displayed meaning it had Error :

> Error: The source report isn't available; it's been deleted or isn't
>   in a folder accessible to the dashboard's running user.

In that case you need to :

1. Delete the report of the dashboard component
2. Re-enter the report back to the dashboard component

Such an easy fix right? Took a whole day to find that out -_-

Once all reports can be seen in the dashboard. Deployment will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Great answer!  In my case, I could pull up the dashboard and everything looked just fine.  When I tried to click into one of the dashlets, though, I got "Data Not Available / The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page."